# How to embed the first child collection form in symfony2 after the parent form is created?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have a form and a collection of forms. I would like to create the Parent form first with no child collection forms, then on the fly if the user try to add the child form it will creates it.

As an example symfony2 has [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) :

```
    // $tag1 = new Tag();
    // $tag1->name = 'tag1';
    // $task->getTags()->add($tag1);
    // $tag2 = new Tag();
    // $tag2->name = 'tag2';
    // $task->getTags()->add($tag2);

    $form = $this->createForm(new TaskType(), $task);
```

My question is how is it possible to add the first child form on the fly. Let's say we don't have the commented part of the code above. TaskType() form can be found [here](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html).

My point here is if I do not have the commented part of my code snippet, there is no way you can create `data-prototype` and use it on the fly. Is there ?

Comment: Did you actually try it to see what would happen?

Comment: Yes, It will be `TaskType` form with no `tagType` form.

Comment: No it wouldn't be. You're now passing a `Task` entity, which does not have any `Tag` entities related to it.

Comment: Yes, I meant that! I wrote in my comment 'with NO tagType'. My question is how can I make that relation on the fly with jQuery?